# c# XML serializer nonamespace using list

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xsd, xml-namespaces

I want to change the xml namespace using a xmlserializer. I have browsed the web with no result. My result from the serializer is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OLPData mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Resource>
    </Resource>
</OLPData>
```

my serializer looks like this:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Resource>), new XmlRootAttribute("OLPData"));
TextWriter t = new StreamWriter("code.xml");
List<Resource> xml = new List<Resource>() { general }s.Serialize(t, xml);
t.Close();
```

so i have a list of the type Ressource, with general as the source. I have tried to add this:

```
public partial class Resource
{
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string attr = @"C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B19\intel_a\startup\Olp\XSchemas\Upload.xsd";
}
```

In the xml class structure, but it obviously adds the noNamespaceSchemaLocation to the ressource instead of the OLDData.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OLPData mlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Resource xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B19\intel_a\startup\Olp\XSchemas\Upload.xsd">
</Resource>
</OLPData>
```

What i want is this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OLPData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B19\intel_a\startup\Olp\XSchemas\Upload.xsd">
  <Resource>
</Resource>
</OLPDate>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea I got, and it seems to work correctly: (**amended** per comments)

```
void Main()
{
    var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OlpData));
    using (var t = new StreamWriter("code.xml"))
    {
        var xml = new OlpData { Resources = new[] { WriteGeneral() } };
        s.Serialize(t, xml);
    }
}

[XmlRoot("OLPData")]
public partial class OlpData
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string attr = @"C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B19\intel_a\startup\Olp\XSchemas\Upload.xsd";

    [XmlElement("Resource")]
    public Resource[] Resources;
}

public partial class Resource
{
}
```

Comment: I can not use var xml = new OlpData { Resources = new[] { new Resource() } };

Comment: @Thomas - Sure, just do whatever you need. Answer amended per your request to use `WriteGeneral`.

Comment: WriteGeneral is a method returning a variable called general, which is a Resource type. Dont know if you understand. And its not a array.

Comment: @Thomas - Yes, it is not an array. So what? I understood, I can see the method below. Did you try the code? It should work fine. If there should be only one Resource, you can remove the array code, I assumed there can be more of them because of the `List` in your original question.

Comment: I have the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'Resource'. Given at WriteGeneralXML.WriteGeneral()

Comment: @Thomas - I have no idea what are you talking about. This has nothing to do with your original problem. If your `WriteGeneral()` function is broken, fix it, since you did not show it to us, I cannot help.

Comment: It works now... thanks!! But i have to remove the following line also: xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", how to?